# Way to create an event to save database in mysql

Tags: mysql, events, phpmyadmin

Is there any way to create an event in phpMyAdmin which will allow me to save database into the folder each week?

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. First, phpMyAdmin is designed to be an interactive GUI, not a scripting interface with an API for you to access. Secondly, there's no way to specifically call phpMyAdmin on any kind of schedule.

If you have command-line and task scheduler (cron, systemd, etc) access, you can script something pretty easily with mysqldump. If not, there are plenty of stand-alone utilities (including some suggestions linked in e4c5's post) which you can call in various ways (MySQL scheduled task, a scheduled task running on your local machine which hits a webpage triggering the dump, and more).